# Should I add validation to DTOs in a DDD architecture?

Tags: domain-driven-design

I typically use `DTOs` to send requests from `Presentation` to `Application` and I use `DTOs` to send back responses from `Application` back to `Presentation`.

I typically decorate the properties of my request `DTOs` with attributes such as `Required`, `StringLength` and so for. But no business rules.

However, I have read in multiple sources that I shouldn't add any sort of validation (such as attributes such as `Required`, `StringLength`, etc.) to `DTOs` at all.

I would like to ask what is the recommended way in light of the DDD literature. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The concept within DDD that is responsible for input validation is **the application service.**

So you should remove the attributes and validate the DTOs in the app service. **Use the DTOs to define structure only, and perform input validation in the app service.**

If you get a lot of duplicated code in different app services (e.g. because they use the same DTO and require the same validation), you can of course extract the validation into a reusable service. Still, the app service *controls* input validation.

Comment: Do you usually return friendly error messages from application services or you just throw? I usually use value objects for validation constraints, which makes it expressive for the domain, but cumbersome to get a nice error report. E.g.`emailAddress = new EmailAddress(dto.emailAddress); account.changeEmail(emailAddress);`. Therefore, I make it the job of the client to make sure he's sending valid commands.

Comment: @plalx Usually I throw an exception that includes a descriptive message, but the message is only meant for developers / debugging purposes. The exceptions should not be triggered in the first place because the client side validation makes sure only valid requests are sent to the server. But of course, anyone can tamper with requests.

Comment: And I also create VOs in the app service from raw data in a not validated state, but validate them immediately against a specification to validate basic business rules.